# Collecting adjacent cells in a 2D grid implemented as a 1D list

Tags: java

The grid is implemented as an `ArrayList<Cell> cells` with the number of columns as `int cols` and `int length = rows * cols`. The `id` of a `Cell` is equal to its position in the list. The first element of `cells` is the top-left cell and the last element is the bottom-right cell.

```
public ArrayList<Cell> getAdjCells(int id) {
    ArrayList<Cell> cs = new ArrayList<>();
    //check if cell is on an edge
    boolean l = id %  cols > 0;        //has left
    boolean u = id >= cols;            //has upper
    boolean r = id %  cols < cols - 1; //has right
    boolean d = id <  length - cols;   //has lower
    //collect all existing adjacent cells
    if (l)      cs.add(cells.get(id - 1       ));
    if (l && u) cs.add(cells.get(id - 1 - cols));
    if (u)      cs.add(cells.get(id     - cols));
    if (u && r) cs.add(cells.get(id + 1 - cols));
    if (r)      cs.add(cells.get(id + 1       ));
    if (r && d) cs.add(cells.get(id + 1 + cols));
    if (d)      cs.add(cells.get(id     + cols));
    if (d && l) cs.add(cells.get(id - 1 + cols));
    return cs;
}
```

I may restructure `ArrayList<Cell> cells` as `Cell[] cells` later on. Return type can be any type of collection really. I just want this function to be as fast as possible, since I have to use it very often.

Comment: Do you need to special-case cells on the boundary or can you allow them to wrap around?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury yes, unfortunately I need to special-case cells on the boundary

Answer (score 1):

Looks good, ship it.

Certainly `cols` is an accurate name, but in this context sometimes people prefer to refer to it as `stride`.

It's close to the initial default, but still, since you know the max size you might specify a capacity: `new ArrayList<>(8);`

Modulo can be slightly expensive. Maybe you want to assign the result to a temp variable, or maybe you trust that JIT already did that for you.

The sequential memory references to {l&u, u, u&r} are cache friendly. The reverse sequence of addresses, {r&d, d, d&l} is perhaps backwards from what you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the method would be faster if the process of determining whether a cell is on an upper or lower edge already uses the prospective index of the adjacent cells. This would probably help mostly for the lower edge check because there's one additive operation less, seeing as the value `id + cols` can be used twice (I don't know if it helps much for the upper edge check, because it doesn't really save an additive operation since `id >= cols + 0` is the same as `id >= cols`). The checks for left and right edges wouldn't benefit from such an approach, because then you'd have to do the modulo twice on different values without saving additive operations (for the right-edge check, it would only move the addition/subtraction of `1` from the modulo comparison to the modulo calculation, and for the left-edge check, it would even increase the number of additive operations needed, because you'd have to calcuate the modulo of `id - 1` and compare it to `cols - 1`, and you'd also have to make a special case for `id - 1 == -1`). However, since you can use the edge neighbor indexes for the corner neighbors, it might help to calculate their prospective indexes in advance anyway.

```java
int leftNeighbor = id - 1;
int upperNeighbor = id - cols;
int rightNeighbor = id + 1;
int lowerNeighbor = id + cols;

int columnOfId = id % cols; //as suggested by J H

boolean hasLeftNeighbor = columnOfId > 0;
boolean hasUpperNeighbor = upperNeighbor >= 0;
boolean hasRightNeighbor = columnOfId < cols - 1;
boolean hasLowerNeighbor = lowerNeighbor < length;
```

The problem with this code is that the potential adjacent indexes will be calculated regardless of whether they are indeed neighbors of the original cell. But this can be easily remedied for the left and right neighbor indexes, since determining their validity doesn't depend on the indexes themselves:

```java
int upperNeighbor = id - cols;
int lowerNeighbor = id + cols;
boolean hasUpperNeighbor = upperNeighbor >= 0;
boolean hasLowerNeighbor = lowerNeighbor < length;

int columnOfId = id % cols; //as suggested by J H
boolean hasLeftNeighbor = columnOfId > 0;
boolean hasRightNeighbor = columnOfId < cols - 1;

if (hasLeftNeighbor) {
    int leftNeighbor = id - 1;
    if (hasUpperNeighbor) {
        int upperLeftNeighbor = upperNeighbor - 1;
    }
    if (hasLowerNeighbor) {
        int lowerLeftNeighbor = lowerNeighbor - 1;
    }
}
if (hasRightNeighbor) {
    int rightNeighbor = id + 1;
    if (hasUpperNeighbor) {
        int upperRightNeighbor = upperNeighbor + 1;
    }
    if (hasLowerNeighbor) {
        int lowerRightNeighbor = lowerNeighbor + 1;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can replace the variable assignments with additions of a cell to `cs`, I just wrote it this way so that it is easier to understand.

The indexes for the lower and upper neighbors are still calculated even though they might not be needed, but for the lower neighbor index, the code is still at worst just as fast as yours (if the index isn't needed), and faster if the index is needed. So the question of whether this code is in sum faster than yours ultimately hinges on the performance impact of calculating the index for the upper neighbor in advance. This probably depends on the number of rows in the list, in that if there are more cells with an upper neighbor than without, I'd guess this code is faster, but you'd probably have to try it out, because, as J H said, who knows what optimizations are already done by the JIT, and in the end, you might only save a couple of microseconds (or so).